# an emergency infusion

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "an emergency infusion" mean "an emergency injection (for preventing COVID-19)"?  Or "an emergency injection (of fresh blood/money into the business to keep it afloat)"?

The New York Times tweeted just now:

> Robinhood, the trading app, said it was raising **an emergency infusion** of more than $1 billion from its existing investors. The app has grappled with an extraordinarily high volume of trading this week as investors have piled into stocks like GameStop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's an emergency injection of cash into the business: more than $1 billion.